# Saving JSON to a file with pretty-print using Powershell

Tags: json, powershell, pretty-print

I'm using powershell on Windows 10. I need to save the json file in a pretty-print indented format.  I have tried various combinations of the code below with no luck.

`$url = example.com/api/someThingy
$saveAs = people.json
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -OutFile $saveAs;`

JSON Sample (There is the possibility that I removed something that makes a difference.)

`{"id":"123456","name":"Lorem", "content":null,"purpose":"<p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>\n<p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>","when":"<ul>\n<li>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem</li>\n</ul>","Purpose":"<p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>\n<p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>"}`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ConvertTo-Json` and save that. Ex.

```
$url = "example.com/api/people"
$saveAs = people.json

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get |
ConvertTo-Json |
Set-Content $saveAs
```

Sample:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo" |
ConvertTo-Json |
Set-Content .\test.txt
```

Comment: This has worked for me in the past, but for some reason in this case it is not working.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Same output as `-outfile`?

Comment: It saves, but did not pretty-paint.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below:

```
$url = example.com/api/people
$saveAs = people.json
$jsonContent = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get;

$prettyJsonContent = ($jsonContent | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json)

$prettyJsonContent *> $saveAs
```

The above code snippet uses PowerShell's `ConvertFrom-Json` and `ConvertTo-Json` to indent the JSON into pretty-print. Then the last line just prints the JSON content to file names as `$saveAs` in the current directory.

Comment: I had issues with duplicate key names with this solution.  Again not represented in my sample above.

Comment: Well then you need to fix the sample. It's one thing to remove sensitive information, but we need to be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I apologize, I think some of the sensitive data is my problem.

Comment: Then replace the values, not the json-structure

Answer (score 1):

Running through Json.net did the trick.

```
$newtonSoftPath = "c:\mycode\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.8.0.3\lib\net40\Newtonsoft.Json.dll";
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($newtonSoftPath);

$url = "example.com/api/people"
$saveAs = "people.json";

$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Get;
#for json array
#$json = [Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray]::Parse($result);

$json = [Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject]::Parse($result);
$json.ToString() | Out-File $saveAs;
```